# Repeat across multiple elements (more than 2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know that I can use `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` to repeat two elements, `<tr>`s for example like this

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in list">
      <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>More text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

but how can I do the same for more than two elements? I want 3 `<tr>`s to be repeated for each item in list. Does Angular have other directives for this purpose or can I surround my repeated elements somehow, so as to be repeated for each item?

Example

```
   <tr>
       <td>Text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Some text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>More text</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: You speak about using only `ng-repeat` with a filter ? And by the way,maybe you could do this : 
`<div ng-repeat="item in list">
      <tr>
       <td>Text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Some text</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>More text</td>
   </tr>
</tr>`

Comment: I just want 3 <tr>s repeated, I don't care much about the way it will be done :)

Comment: can you display list object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in list">
      <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
      <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For more reference check above link:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Great! All <tr>s are repeated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Also a more simple way to do this without making this kind of ... weird thing, is the following :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list"> 
   <tr> 
      <td>{{item}}</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td>{{item}}</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
      <td>{{item}}</td> 
   </tr> 
</tr>
```

No need to use start, end .. for this particular use case